# Get number of unread messages via Gmail API

Tags: ios, gmail, gmail-api

[This sample](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ios) allows me to fetch some labels from Gmail interface. The question is: Is it possible to fetch the number of a user's unread messages in Gmail, using the same tools in the sample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very good at objective-c, but you can [get every message with the `UNREAD`-label](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get?authuser=1#try-it) and check the unread count:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/UNREAD?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "UNREAD",
 "name": "UNREAD",
 "type": "system",
 "messagesTotal": 354,
 "messagesUnread": 354,
 "threadsTotal": 320,
 "threadsUnread": 320
}
```

As you can see, `messagesUnread` tells me I have `354` unread messages.

Comment: As far as I understood, I should send this request manually (i.e using AFNetworking library), right?

Comment: @ArtStyle That's what I usually do. I don't use any client library at all, but just do manual requests. There is functionality for this in the ios client library, but I'm terrible at it, so I can't help you with that.